# "cakephp 3, save not working, Unknown type"

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Here is the link [CakePHP 3 Saving BelongsToMany Association Unknown type "" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32017981/cakephp-3-saving-belongstomany-association-unknown-type-error) that I used to first, but could not solve the problem.

I have 3 tables:

1. Bookings
2. Travelers
3. BookingsTravelers

When I save the data in the bookings table I get the error metioned above, see below image:

[image]

The models associations look like this:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('bookings_travelers');
    $this->displayField('name');
    $this->primaryKey('bPassID');

    $this->belongsTo('Bookings', [
        'foreignKey' => 'booking_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Travelers', [
        'foreignKey' => 'traveler_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
}

public function initialize(array $config)
{

    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('bookings');
    $this->displayField('idbooking');
    $this->primaryKey('idbooking');

    $this->belongsTo('Users', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);


    $this->belongsToMany('Travelers', [
        'joinTable' => 'bookings_travelers',
    ]);
}

public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('travelers');
    $this->displayField('name');
    $this->primaryKey('travelers_id');


    $this->belongsToMany('Bookings', [
        'joinTable' => 'bookings_travelers',
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace from the logs.

Comment: @AmanRawat, The issue is resolved. Basically, there was some cakephp naming convention violation in the declarations.

Comment: ok Great then provide the answer for it. So it will be helpful to other

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically I had to rename the 'idbooking' to 'id' only after changing the database column name, and it worked. My bad, a silly mistake.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. I had "userid" and I had to change that to just "id" in order to solve the problem.

Comment: @BigGreenAlligator, I'm glad it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, got here with the same error and in my case the problem was that i've had renamed the PK field after the table was created and then run
 `cake bake model table`. It seems that this command will not update properly our Model/Table/tableTable.php file, so i had to manually update the following fields to match with the new PK name:

```
    $this->setDisplayField('newpkname');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('newpkname');
```

Hope it helps someone :)